# How to make wrapper for spatie/laravel-permission Contracts/Permission?

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

In  Laravel 8 app using  spatie/laravel-permission ^3.18 I
defined in bootstrap/app.php

```
if ( ! defined("PERMISSION_USE_SERVICES")) {
    define("PERMISSION_USE_SERVICES", 'Use services');
}
```

and in init seeder :

```
$CustomerRole = Role::create(['name' => ROLE_CUSTOMER, 'guard_name' => 'web']);
$customerUseServicesPermission = Permission::create(['name' => PERMISSION_USE_SERVICES, 'guard_name' => 'web']);
$CustomerRole->givePermissionTo($customerUseServicesPermission); // means : customer use services
```

and when I register new user in app/Actions/Fortify/CreateNewUser.php I want to give new user
customerUseServicesPermission.

In vendor/spatie/laravel-permission/src/Contracts/Permission.php I found method :

```
interface Permission
{
  public static function findByName(string $name, $guardName): self;
```

But using it I got error :

```
Cannot call abstract method Spatie\Permission\Contracts\Permission::findByName()
```

have I to make wrapper file for Contracts/Permission.php and in which way ?

Thanks!

Comment: Accessing laravel-permission model you access it with "use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;"  "use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;" instead of "use Spatie\Permission\Contracts\Permission;" for more info https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/advanced-usage/seeding